# How to convert a column of string array to array format and coalesce the first non null value in the dataset

Tags: string, list, sas, coalesce, proc-sql

I have dataset which consists of two columns. Where "Values" column consists of string in list/array and the column datatype is char. I need to get coalesce first non null value in the new column since we also have null values other rows. I am new to SAS. Could you please help me with the solution.

[image]

Required Output
[image]

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  Why is the required output just 1 for both example inputs? What is the actual logic?   That is not really a very useful way to store the values are they will be extremely difficult to work with.  Explain more what you plan to do with this data to get advice on how to restructure it.

Comment: Are you just asking out to tease the first value from that string?  Use SCAN() function.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by null value.  How would such a value be represented in source  string? Show example input/output for strings that have null values before the first non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a long string with comma separated values?  You can use SCAN() to select one item from the list.  Since your list has extra `[` and `]` you can just include those extra characters in the set of delimiter characters for SCAN().

```
 data want;
   set have;
   first = scan(values,1,'[,]');
 run;
```

If the values can include the delimiter use the 'q' modifier. That will ignore delimiters that are inside of quoted strings. If you want to remove the quotes from the result use the DEQUOTE() function.

```
 data want;
   set have;
   first = dequote(scan(values,1,'[,]','q'));
 run;
```

Comment: One other possibility is if there are null values in the first observation of the array (e.g. `'["", "", "1", "2", "3"]'`. In that case, if you remove all commas, brackets and quotes, you end up with a space-separated list where the first value is always valid: `first_valid = scan(compress(row, '[],"'), 1);`